# SQL injection-proofing TextBoxes

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-injection

I've found some tutorials on this already, but they aren't exactly what I'm looking for, I can use the following for username fields and password fields

```vb
Private Sub UsernameTextBox_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles UsernameTextBox.KeyPress
    If Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) OrElse Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) OrElse Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) Then
        e.Handled = False
    Else
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

But for an email field how would I go about protecting against SQL injection for that textbox, as some email accounts have periods or dashes in them?

**Update:**
Below is an example of an insert statement I use.

```
Dim con As SqlConnection
con = New SqlConnection()
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
 Try
  con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & Server & ";Initial Catalog=" & Database & ";User ID=" & User & ";Password=" & Password & ";"
  con.Open()
  cmd.Connection = con
  cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TB_User(STRUserID, password, Email) VALUES('" & UsernameTextBox.Text & "', '" & MD5Hash(PasswordTextBox.Text) & "', '" & EmailTextBox.Text & "')"
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch ex As Exception
  MessageBox.Show("Error while inserting record on table..." & ex.Message, "Insert Records")
Finally
  con.Close()
End Try
```

So I need to run this with parametrized queries rather than how I'm doing it now?

Comment: Older article, but good description:   http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of filtering out "invalid" data from user input, consider using parametrized queries and not putting user input directly into your queries; that's very bad form.

To run your current query using parameters, it's pretty easy:

```vb
Dim con As New SqlConnection()
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()

Try
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & Server & ";Initial Catalog=" & Database & ";User ID=" & User & ";Password=" & Password & ";"
    con.Open()
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TB_User(STRUserID, password, Email) VALUES(@username, @password, @email)"
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = UsernameTextBox.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.Char, 32).Value = MD5Hash(PasswordTextBox.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = EmailTextBox.Text
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("Error while inserting record on table..." & ex.Message, "Insert Records")
Finally
    con.Close()
End Try
```

All you have to do is use `cmd.Parameters.Add` with a parameter name and the right database type (the ones I guessed probably don't match up, so you'll want to change them), then set the value to the value you want used in the query. Parameter names start with an `@`.

Comment: I agree, it is extremely difficult to predict all the possible ways someone can inject SQL into an open text field.   Much better to use parameterized queries and let SQL prevent the injection...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, not quite as direct as I was looking for because I'm still quite new to VB.Net and SQL.  I will look through google about what you suggested and hopefully can put it to use.

Perhaps you can post a link to an MSDN article or tutorial to help guide me?

Comment: @BrentHacker: This is a pretty good one: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/accessing-the-database-directly-from-an-aspnet-page/using-parameterized-queries-with-the-sqldatasource-vb

Comment: Thanks, I've udpated my question btw

Comment: TBH The guides I've seen so far are still leaving me in the dust, but that's just due to my knowledge level and the lack of hard examples from the guides, no fault to you so I'll accept your answer lol!

Comment: @BrentHacker: Okay, I've updated my answer - you might find it a little easier to understand, since it's (I find, at least) the simplest way out of many.

Comment: Awesome!!!! Extremely appreciate this.  Since you did the work for me pretty much I'll do my part and read up on how this works.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't depend on the textbox. Don't compose a sql sentence joining strings like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM User WHERE UserName=" + tbName.Text + ...
```

Use stored procedures or parameterized queries and you'll be safe from SQL injection.

When you use parameters, the textbox content is used as a value, so it doesn't matter what it contains.

Answer (score 0):

Use a parametrized query like this:

```vb
Using conn = New SqlConnection("some connection string")
    Using cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT Password FROM tblUser WHERE UserName = @Name", conn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("Name", UsernameTextBox.Text))
        conn.Open()
        Dim password As String = DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), String)
        Console.WriteLine(password)
    End Using
End Using
```

This is injection safe!