# My code was working earlier until I added error messages for checking if CapNum is empty or already existed on the database

Tags: mysql, vb.net, xampp

```
Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
cmd = con.CreateCommand
con.Open()
Try
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(capNum.Text.ToString()) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill up the Capstone Number to proceed.")
    Else
        Dim theQuery As String = "select * from listofcapstone where caps_Number like '%" & capNum.Text & "%'"
        Dim cmd1 As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(theQuery, con)
        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader()
        If reader.HasRows Then
            reader.Close()
            MessageBox.Show("There's already an existing data with this Capstone Number!")
        Else
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into listofcapstone(caps_Number, thesis_Title, ictdu_entNumber, year, course)values(@caps_Number, @thesis_Title, @ictdu_entNumber, @year, @course)"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@caps_Number", capNum.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@thesis_Title", title.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ictdu_entNumber", ictduCapNum.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", yr.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@course", course.Text)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("SUCCESSFULLY ADDED!")
            capNum.Clear()
            title.Clear()
            ictduCapNum.Clear()
            course.Clear()
            yr.SelectedIndex = -1
        End If
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("Connection Lost!!")
    Me.Close()
End Try
con.Close()
```

Comment: And what is it doing now? Don't keep us in suspense!  ALWAYS provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the issue.  Error messages are always relevant.  Actual behaviour that differs from expected is always relevant.  Also, have you debugged the code?  If you haven't set a breakpoint and stepped through code, examining relevant variables and other expressions as you go, then it's too early to be posting here.  If you don't know how to do that, now would be a good time to learn.

Comment: Ive already found the problem..on the
 <pre>
 If reader.HasRows Then
                    reader.Close()
                    MessageBox.Show("There's already an existing data with this Capstone Number!")
                Else
                                        cmd.CommandText = "insert into listofcapstone(caps_Number, thesis_Title, ictdu_entNumber, year, course)values(. . . . . . . . .)"
</pre>

on the else part i forgot to close the reader

Comment: If you have solved your own issue, you should add an answer that describes what you did and then accept it.  It may help someone else with a similar problem and it may lead to one of us indicating what would be a better solution.

Comment: I'm sorry about that..I'm new to this kind of field and just notice this site..I really want to improve so I tried this site..and thank you sir for the suggestion and help

Comment: IMO: I advise to break the code into two subs: one dealing with the UI (capNum.Text check, etc) and call a routine that do the insert into the database, When you have all code mix up, it's hard to maintain later.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem on my code..i tried to remove try and catch to see which part of the code wasnt used properly and receive the "MySqlException was unhandled" error message..then put a reader on the else part

```
Dim theQuery As String = "select * from listofcapstone where caps_Number like '%" & capNum.Text & "%'"
Dim cmd1 As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(theQuery, con)
Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader()
If reader.HasRows Then
    reader.Close()
    MessageBox.Show("There's already an existing data with this Capstone Number!")
Else
    reader.Close() 'Where I put the reader.'
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into listofcapstone(caps_Number, thesis_Title, ictdu_entNumber, year, course)values(@caps_Number, @thesis_Title, @ictdu_entNumber, @year, @course)"
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@caps_Number", capNum.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@thesis_Title", title.Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `parameterized queries` instead of concatenating your queries like you're doing with that `SELECT` statement in order to mitigate `SQL Injection` attacks. You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9813155/5395709) and [this](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) to learn more about it.

You can also use the `Using` statement that will dispose of any object that has implemented the `IDisposable` interface such as the `MySqlConnection` and `MySqlCommand` objects. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement):

> Sometimes your code requires an unmanaged resource, such as a file
>   handle, a COM wrapper, or a SQL connection. A Using block guarantees
>   the disposal of one or more such resources when your code is finished
>   with them. This makes them available for other code to use.

You can also break down into separate Sub routines the queries for retrieving a record and inserting a new one. I put together a basic example showing what I discussed:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports MySql.Data
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Namespace MySqlCmdExample
    Class Program
        Private Shared Sub Main(args As String())
            Dim dataProvider As New AlbumDataProvider()

            Try
                If dataProvider.AlbumExists("Album_Five") Then
                    Console.WriteLine("Album exists...")

                    Return
                End If

                Console.WriteLine("Adding new album...")
                dataProvider.AddAlbum(3, "Album_Five")
            Catch ex As MySqlException
                Console.WriteLine([String].Format("Oops, an error occurred: {0}", ex.Message))
            End Try
        End Sub
    End Class

    Public Class AlbumDataProvider
        Private connectionString As String = "server=localhost;user=<your_username>;database=stack_overflow;port=3306;password=<your_password>"

        Public Sub New()
        End Sub

        Public Function AlbumExists(name As String) As Boolean
            Dim found As Boolean = False

            Using conn As New MySqlConnection(connectionString)
                If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                    conn.Open()
                End If

                Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Album WHERE `Name` = @albumName", conn)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@albumName", name)

                Using reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    found = reader.HasRows
                End Using
            End Using

            Return found
        End Function

        Public Sub AddAlbum(ownerId As Integer, name As String)
            Using conn As New MySqlConnection(connectionString)
                If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                    conn.Open()
                End If

                Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO Album(OwnerId, Name) VALUES(@ownerId, @albumName)", conn)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ownerId", ownerId)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@albumName", name)

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: thank you so much for the suggestion sir :D I see your point about concatenated sql strings.. ill take a note about it..

Comment: @Brzak Not a problem.